# importlib.reload does not reload pip installed modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

It seems that importlib is not willing to reload reinstalled modules

```
>>> import [my_pip_installable]
>>> [my_pip_installable].[my_code]
[original_output]
```

Then, go and edit [my_code] in [my_pip_installable] and push to github.  Upgrade the package in another console.

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade git+https://github.com/[my_user]/[my_pip_installable]
```

... In the original interpreter

```
>>> importlib.reload([my_pip_installable])
>>> [my_pip_installable].[my_code] # expect [updated_output]
[original_output]
```

Is there a way to reload a non-local module?